# Pass a structure to a function

Tags: c, function, structure

I know you can pass specific elements of a structure to a function, but is it possible to pass an entire structure, similar to how you could pass an entire 1 dimensional array?  I'm trying to pass movie num[1,2,3] etc. to a function.  I'm pretty sure you could pass it using a for loop, but is it possible to pass the structure in its entirety without a loop?  My code is below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void InputData(struct movie *num[50]);

int main()
{
    struct movie
    {
        char name[50];
        int curatornum;
        int votes;
    };

    struct movie *num[50];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
    {
        num[i] = (struct movie *)malloc(1 * sizeof(struct movie *));
    }

    InputData(num);

    for (int i = 50; i > 0; i--)
    {
        free(num[i]);
    }
}

void InputData(struct movie *num[50])
{
    //Compiler gives an error: conflicting types for 'InputData'void InputData(struct movie *num[50]
}
```

Comment: Your struct is inside main after the function declaration

Comment: I intentionally put the structure within the main function.  From what I've read, it's generally considered bad practice to put variables as global items, but it seems like structures are generally ok to keep global.  I'm attempting to pass the address of the structure to another function.

Comment: Right the shape of the struct is something that should be reused

Comment: The struct declaration is not a variable.   It is a declaration of a structure.  It needs to precede the first mention  of `struct movie`, in this case before the first declaration of `InputData`.

Comment: `num` is an array of pointers to `struct movie`. That is, each pointer in `num` should point to a region of memory that holds a `struct movie`. Yet `num[i] = (struct movie *)malloc(1 * sizeof(struct movie *));` is allocating only enough memory to hold a _pointer_ for each of these. Instead you should allocate for `sizeof (struct movie)`;. The posted use of `malloc` is not idiomatic C. First, usually C programmers don't cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: Second, and this would have solved the mis-allocation problem, it is idiomatic to do something like `num[i] = malloc(sizeof *num[0]);` or `num[i] = malloc(sizeof **num)` instead. Here the type of the expression `*num[0]` is used to calculate the size of the allocation. This is less error prone than writing explicit types, especially when types change eventually. Also, you should be checking the value returned by `malloc` to be sure that allocations were successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can return the entire structure, or just the address of one. You can even return an array of nested things and so on.

You can use of a loop and pass each movie, but that would imply and calling the function for each element and I believe this is not what you want to do.

### About the provided code

The are many problems in the code, and this is probably not the best way to write this in `C`.

> **I will add below 2 examples: one with some changes to the original code and other using a common way to write this in `C`**

#### *one-of* errors

```
    for(int i=0; i<=50; i++)
    {
        num[i]=(struct movie *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct movie *));
    }
    InputData(num);
    for(int i=50; i>0; i--)
    {
        free(num[i]);
    }
```

The compiler warned you about this: from `0` to `50` there are `51` values. These loops are wrong.

And there is no reason to invert the order to free an array of pointers. You do this when you have pointers to dynamic data **inside** a dynamic structure: then you must free the areas allocated inside and then going up free'ing the `struct` itself.

#### `InputData()`

```
    void InputData(struct movie *num[50]);
```

No, do not return `void`: it is a waste, many times an error. Here you could simply return the adress of an array of `struct movie`.

Here `InputData` gets and array of 50 pointers to `struct movie`. `num` is `struct movie* [50]` as your IDE can probably tell you.

Not entering in religious discussion here, but in `C` you declare a name for a variable of a type. If the type is a pointer, so be it. If `num` is a pointer then it is clear that `*num` is a value of the thing `num` points to. It is called dereferencing and it is basic `C`. But it not what you declare.

If `num` is `int*` then `*num` is an `int`. But you declare `num`.

So it is easier to reason about this

```
    struct movie*                   num[50];
```

than to read

```
    struct movie                    *num[50];
```

because you are declaring `num` as `struct movie* [50]`.

#### making `InputData()` work in the original code

Anyway, you have in `main`

```
    struct movie*                  num[50];
```

And this is the `static` data you want `InputData` to act upon: an array of 50 pointers to a `struct`. So you need to pass its address to `InputData` and it is what your compiler is trying to tell you
with something like

```
warning C4133: 'function': incompatible types - from 'movie *[50]' to 'movie **'
```

Changing the argument in `InputData()` to

```
    void   InputData(Movie* (*num)[50]);
```

would tell the compiler that `InputData` will receive a pointer to the array of pointers.

The common way of write this is to allocate the array **inside** `InputData` and return its address. *See the second example*

This code is from the example I will left below:

```c
    Movie* num[50] = {0};
    InputData(&num);
    printf(
        "\
    First movie is \"%s\", num = %6d, votes = %2d\n\
     Last movie is \"%s\", num = %6d, votes = %2d\n\
\n",
        num[0]->name, num[0]->curatornum, num[0]->votes,
        (*num[49]).name, (*num[49]).curatornum, (*num[49]).votes);
```

So you see that the array `num` is declared in `main` and its address is passed to `InputData()`. The function uses this area to write the data in. And you see here the 2 common notations in the `printf` to display the first and last movie of the array.

#### Use a *factory* function

When writing these kind of code never write interactive code. It makes testing a PITA. See this function:

```
Movie* factory()
{
    static int num   = 1;
    Movie*     movie = malloc(sizeof(Movie));
    if (movie == NULL) return NULL;  // malloc failed
    int value         = rand();
    movie->curatornum = num * 1000 + value % 1000;
    movie->votes      = value % 10;
    sprintf(movie->name, "Title %07d", num);
    num += 1;
    return movie;
}
```

Anytime you call it you get a `Movie`, repeatable, reliable. From the example:

```
void InputData(Movie* (*num)[50])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 50; i += 1)
        (*num)[i] = factory();
}
```

this version of `InputData()` gets the data right away. Always. 50 or 50,000 movies.

Here are the 1st and last movies in a run of the example:

```
    First movie is "Title 0000001", num =   1650, votes =  1
     Last movie is "Title 0000050", num =  50161, votes =  2
```

And the math in `factory()` helps to see if the values are ok.

#### use a `typedef`

You may find it easier to use

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    int  curatornum;
    int  votes;
} Movie;
```

And reference `Movie` in code instead of `struct movie` every time. This is also a religious thing, anyway.

### The example, using the provided code with minimum changes

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77809883/passing-structure-through-function
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    int  curatornum;
    int  votes;
} Movie;

Movie* factory();
void   InputData(Movie* (*num)[50]);

int main(void)
{
    srand(241012);
    Movie* num[50] = {0};
    InputData(&num);
    printf(
        "\
    First movie is \"%s\", num = %6d, votes = %2d\n\
     Last movie is \"%s\", num = %6d, votes = %2d\n\
\n",
        num[0]->name, num[0]->curatornum, num[0]->votes,
        (*num[49]).name, (*num[49]).curatornum, (*num[49]).votes);
}

void InputData(Movie* (*num)[50])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 50; i += 1)
        (*num)[i] = factory();
}

Movie* factory()
{
    static int num   = 1;
    Movie*     movie = malloc(sizeof(Movie));
    if (movie == NULL) return NULL;  // malloc failed
    int value         = rand();
    movie->curatornum = num * 1000 + value % 1000;
    movie->votes      = 1 + value % 10;
    sprintf(movie->name, "Title %07d", num);
    num += 1;
    return movie;
}
```

#### output

```
    First movie is "Title 0000001", num =   1650, votes =  1
     Last movie is "Title 0000050", num =  50161, votes =  2
```

### A second example: use a *container object*

Here is a common way to write this kind of program, one that is easier and extensible.

Here we have a `Movie` thing and some functions to operate on `Movie`

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    int  curatornum;
    int  votes;
} Movie;

Movie* factory();
int    show_movie(Movie*, const char*);
```

But our data is not a `Movie`, it is a collection of `Movie`. *java* uses this name, C++ uses *container*.

Here we have `Movies` and some functions to operate **on the collection itself**

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t  capacity;
    size_t  size;
    Movie** M;  // pointers to movies
} Movies;

Movies* InputData(size_t);
int     show_movies(Movies*, const char*);
Movies* free_movies(Movies*);
```

It is easier to understand if `InputData` returns a set of `Movie`, but we do not see `Movie` here. It is the concept of *encapsulation*: we can change the content of `Movies` at will.

```
    Movies* cat = InputData(10);
```

returns `cat` with 10 `Movie` using `factory` and it is very easy to follow

Here is `main` for the second example

```
int main(void)
{
    srand(241012);
    Movies* cat = InputData(10);
    show_movies(cat, "***** A simple test *****\n\n");
    free_movies(cat);
    return 0;
}
```

- `srand()`is perfect for testing since it will give always the same sequence during testing
- `InputData` will get the address of a collection of `Movies`.
- `show_movies` will do his thing and accepts a handy message for testing
- `free_movies` will erase the catalog

#### output of the example

```
***** A simple test *****
  10 of 10 movies:

  0     "Title 0000001", num =   1650, votes =  1
  1     "Title 0000002", num =   2399, votes = 10
  2     "Title 0000003", num =   3107, votes =  8
  3     "Title 0000004", num =   4023, votes =  4
  4     "Title 0000005", num =   5744, votes =  5
  5     "Title 0000006", num =   6209, votes = 10
  6     "Title 0000007", num =   7350, votes =  1
  7     "Title 0000008", num =   8950, votes =  1
  8     "Title 0000009", num =   9856, votes =  7
  9     "Title 0000010", num =  10703, votes =  4
```

#### complete code

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77809883/passing-structure-through-function

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    int  curatornum;
    int  votes;
} Movie;

Movie* factory();
int    show_movie(Movie*, const char*);


typedef struct
{
    size_t  capacity;
    size_t  size;
    Movie** M;  // pointers to movies
} Movies;

Movies* InputData(size_t);
int     show_movies(Movies*, const char*);
Movies* free_movies(Movies*);

int main(void)
{
    srand(241012);
    Movies* cat = InputData(10);
    show_movies(cat, "***** A simple test *****\n\n");
    free_movies(cat);
    return 0;
}

Movies* InputData(size_t cap)
{
    Movies* cat = malloc(sizeof(Movies));
    if (cat == NULL) return NULL;
    cat->capacity = cap;
    cat->size     = cap;  // will return the catalog full
    cat->M        = (Movie**)malloc(cap * sizeof(Movie*));
    if (cat->M == NULL)
    {
        free(cat);
        return NULL;
    }
    // get the movies into the catalog
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cap; i += 1)
        cat->M[i] = factory();
    return cat;
}

int show_movies(Movies* cat, const char* msg)
{ 
    if (cat == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);  // optional title
    printf(
        "  %llu of %llu movies:\n\n", cat->size, cat->capacity);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cat->size; i += 1)
    {
        char index[8];
        sprintf(index, "  %llu\t", i);
        show_movie(cat->M[i], index);
    }
    return 0;
}

Movies* free_movies(Movies* cat)
{
    if (cat == NULL) return NULL;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cat->size; i += 1)
        free(cat->M[i]);
    free(cat->M);
    free(cat);
    return NULL;
}

Movie* factory()
{
    static int num   = 1;
    Movie*     movie = malloc(sizeof(Movie));
    if (movie == NULL) return NULL;  // malloc failed
    int value         = rand();
    movie->curatornum = num * 1000 + value % 1000;
    movie->votes      = 1 + value % 10;
    sprintf(movie->name, "Title %07d", num);
    num += 1;
    return movie;
}

int show_movie(Movie* m, const char* msg)
{
    if (m == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);  // optional title
    printf(
        "\"%s\", num = %6d, votes = %2d\n", m->name,
        m->curatornum, m->votes);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code is very helpful.  I don't have a programming background, I've just read a "C for dummies" book, but it is missing a lot of stuff, like factories.  Factories do seem very useful though!

Comment: _factory functions_ are really useful. Can save hours of testing just for not being at the console typing boring data for fields. For this reason things like [faker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@faker-js/faker) are so popular in other fields. And math is a friend. Look at the 3rd title in the example: `"Title 0000004", num =   4023, votes =  4`: the title is `4`, so `num` is `4*1000 + 23` and the votes are `23%10 + 1 = 4`. So you can test for corruption in the values for any record.

Comment: Also important is the notion of _encapsulation_  seeing `Movies` instead of `Movie`: the notion of containment, treating the `structs` only as a whole

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to pass an entire structure through a function,

Yes. Pass by value is the norm which, if you do it carelessly, will do a lot of copying.

> I'm trying to push movie num[1,2,3] etc. through a function ...

That's the careless copying mentioned above.

You need to pass a pointer and size to the function consuming the data. Copying will ruin the performance.

Comment: What would the syntax of that look like roughly?  Would I need to do something like for(int I=0; I<49; I++){InputData(num[I]->name, num[I]->votes... etc)?

Comment: @Ratdude The idiomatic way is `pointer-to-data, number-of-elements`